# Django slug throws me an error and url is not matching

Tags: python, django

I've followed the advice I was given but the slug still does not show in the url. When I try to run it I get the following error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8080/blog/1/
Raised by:  blog.views.detail
```

I was told if I changed the values in my views from

```
  detail(request, blog_id):
    page = "blog/detail.html"
    title = "Detail"
    context = {
      "post": get_object_or_404(Post, pk=blog_id),
   }
```

to this

```
   detail(request, slug):
       page = "blog/detail.html"
       title = "Detail"
       context = {
        "post": get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug),
      }
```

and changed my url to look like this

```
 url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

it would work but it does not. Heres my code as it is now below.

My post model in models.py looks like this

```
  from django.db import models

  class Post(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   body = models.TextField()
   slug = models.SlugField()
   img = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
   updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
   categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
   tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title

   class Meta:
       ordering = ["-created"]
```

my views.py looks like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post

def detail(request, slug):
   page = "blog/detail.html"
   title = "Detail"
   context = {
      "post": get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug),
      "title": title,
   }
   return render(request, page, context)
```

my blog/urls.py look like this

```
from django.conf.urls import url
app_name = 'blog'

from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /blog/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    # ex: /blog/5/
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),

    # ex: /blog/contact
    url(r'^contact$', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

my site/urls.py looks like this

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', 'blog.views.land'),
]
```

my admin.py looks like this

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Post, Author, Category, Tag


class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
    search_fields = ['title', 'body']
    list_display = ['title', 'body', 'created']
    list_filter = ['created']

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

any and all help guidance advice or tutorial is invited and welcomed. Thanks

Comment: So what URL are you going to now, after those changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the regex is this

```
(?P<slug>[\w-]+)
```

when it should be this

```
(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)
```

thanks to all that tried to help. I'm glad I didn't give up. This made my new years!!!

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from your post: you tried url `http://localhost:8080/blog/1/`, but that is the old url, you need new URL which is going to be something like `http://localhost:8080/blog/slug/`...

You should also change `get_object_or_404(Post, slug)` to `get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)`.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/shortcuts/#get_object_or_404 for details, get expects keyword arguments, not positional: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get

Comment: No, you did not have it like that.  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34522466/revisions

Comment: I had it like that under that code. If you looked at all of it, you would've seen it

Answer (score 0):

Check if you really have a post with slug `1`. It seems to me that you used `/blog/1` to get the post by `pk` and so now it won't work as the post with slug `1` doesn't exist at all.